# Capybara/Rspec not catching ActionController::UnpermittedParameters error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I was in the processing in adding a field to an ActiveRecord model and the corresponding view.  Before I started, I had a full green test run.  I started with writing the following test:

```
scenario "with all correct info" do
  create_vendor "vendor.email@example.com", "vendor_passowrd"
  create_consumer "consumer.email@example.com", "password"
  sign_in_with "consumer.email@example.com", "password"
  click_link "New Order"
  select 'vendor.email@example.com', from: "Vendor"
  fill_in "Order text", with: "my normal order"
  click_button "Submit"

  expect(page).to have_content "my normal order"
end
```

I added the field to the model using the proper rails migration and the route entry.

I would have expected the test to fail with a ActionController::UnpermittedParameters because I have not yet updated the controller.  However, this is the failure I am getting:

"Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content "my normal order"

When I test in the browser, I do get the ActionController::UnpermittedParameters, but not in the automated test.

My question is should the test get the ActionController::UnpermittedParameters error?

Answer (score 0):

Capybara simulates a web browser request, so it will get back an error page from Rails. The `UnpermittedParameters` error will not propagate up to the spec code itself.

This sounds like it's working correctly.